# How to connect an xib to my application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created an application in iphone. i have created all my controller files without an xib. After the controllers have seperatedly created xib from the user interface section and and i started linking the xibs that i have created  seperatedly with my controllers .But the problem is that it does get connected with my class.How to connect the xib with my class.Please anybody help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open inspector for the xib file
2. go to the last tab of it
3. select the controller class for the xib

then open the xib and open the interface builder and make the connection with the view component if you have any

run and enjoy.

Comment: thank u for u r answer sir it is working properly but i am getting a problem my rootviewcontroller is not taking my tableview object directly.What may be the problem .Thank u sir